# iTunes naming pattern different on Windows and Mac

Tags: windows, macos, itunes, filenames

On my Windows machine iTunes renames and moves all my imported TV episodes to the following format:

`TV Shows/[show]/Season [Season#]/[Season#]-[Episode# with 1 leading 0] [Episode Name]`

but on my Mac running OS X it is

`TV Shows/[show]/Season [Season#]/[Episode# with 1 leading 0] [Episode Name]`

Now if I connect the Mac drive to my Windows machine (external HFS+ HDD read on Windows using [Paragon's HFS+ driver](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows-free/), and sets that as the library in iTunes, then Windows uses the same pattern as the Mac.

Where do I change this naming pattern? Can I use a custom one?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't Windows vs Mac, it's instead what metadata is stored in the files.

If there is a value for the disk number on the file then the filename will be
`[Disk#]-[Episode# with 1 leading 0] [Episode Name]`.
Note that this is the same as written in the question but the number at the start of the filename is the disk number and not the season number.